# Divisibility of integer numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, integers

If we have two integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a = \frac{5b}{6}$, is $a$ divisible by $5$?

If so, why is that?

I don't see it.

Comment: Hint: consider the prime factorization of $b$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Unique Factorization Theorem?

Comment: Intuitively, you should note that dividing by $6=2\cdot 3$ cannot take away a factor $5$

Answer (score 1):

No prime factorisation is really required here: we have $5b=6a$,so $5$ divides $6a$. Now $5$ is prime, hence  by *Euclid's lemma*, it must divide one of the factors. As it does not divide $6$, it must divide $a$.

Answer (score -1):

If $a$ is an integer then $b = 6k, k\in \mathbb{Z}$ so $$a = 5k \Rightarrow a \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$$

Comment: Could you please explain the downvote?

Answer (score -1):

If $a$ is an integer, then it is obvious that $6$ divides $5b$ or more specifically $b$.

Hence we can say that, $b=6k$ for some integer $k$.

So $a=5k$

Thus we can conclude that $5$ divides $a$, since $5$ divides $5$.

Comment: @user309293 If you like my answer, you can accept it by clicking the "tick" mark on the left side of my answer, or even you can upvote it. :-)

Comment: Also why is this answer downvote?

Comment: Why the downvote?